# Calculate 2 table where condition - Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

i have 2 table ,

produk table

```
id  produk  batch   qty
1   AAA    ADADAD   2
2   BBB    ADADAD   2
3   BBB    AAAAAA   2
...............
```

and move table,

```
id  produk  batch   qty
1   BBB     ADADAD  1
```

and i want showing table after qty from stok table minus qty from move table, what i want table

```
PRODUK  BATCH   QTY
AAA     ADADAD  2
BBB     ADADAD  1
BBB     AAAAAA  2
```

and this my query

```
var obj = _db.produk
       .Groupby(a=> new {a.code,a.batch})
       .Select(a=> new {
          produk = a.key.code,
          batch = a.Key.batch,
          qty = _db.move.Where(c => a.Any(p => p.code == a.code && p.batch == a.batch)).Sum(a=>a.qty)
       }).tolist();
```

but not working

Comment: Do a union between the profile table and the move table, except that the move table should have a negated qty. You then do a groupby on the result of the union.

Comment: The other solution is to have a groupby query for the produk, a groupby query for the move, then a join query between the two previous queries, taking care of outer join cases. The first solution is simpler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could also query the `produck` table, then, in the Select statement, filter the `move` table based on the produck's `batch` and `produck` properties, then calculate the `qty`.

Code as below:

```
        List<Produk> produks = new List<Produk>()
        {
            new Produk(){ id = 1, produk= "AAA", batch="ADADAD", qty = 2},
            new Produk(){ id = 2, produk= "BBB", batch="ADADAD", qty = 2},
            new Produk(){ id = 3, produk= "BBB", batch="AAAAAA", qty = 2},
        };

        List<Remove> removes = new List<Remove>()
        {
            new Remove(){ id=1, produk="BBB", batch="ADADAD", qty=1}
        };

        var result = (from p in produks
                      select new Produk
                      {
                          id = p.id,
                          produk = p.produk,
                          batch = p.batch,
                          qty = p.qty - removes.Where(c => c.produk == p.produk && c.batch == p.batch).Sum(c => c.qty)
                      }).ToList();
```

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem really efficient. For every `produk` record you scan through the whole `removes` collection. In MSSQL it could result into a *Nested Loops* instead of *Merge Join*.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do LEFT JOIN to grouped move table.

```
var moves =
  from m in _db.move
  group m by { m.code, m.batch } into g
  select
  {
      g.Key.code,
      g.Key.batch,
      qty = g.Sum(x => x.qty)
  };

var query = 
   from p in _db.produk
   join m in moves on new { p.code, p.batch } equals { m.code, m.batch } into j
   from m in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new
   {
       produk = p.code,
       batch = p.batch.
       qty = p.qty - (int?)m.qty ?? 0
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer method syntax over query syntax then you can write your query as this:

```cs
var availableItems = repository
    .GroupJoin(purchases,
        stock => new { stock.Product, stock.Batch }, 
        move => new { move.Product, move.Batch },
        (stock, moves) => new { Stock = stock, Moves = moves })
    .SelectMany(
        stockAndRelatedMoves => stockAndRelatedMoves.Moves.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        (stockAndRelatedMoves, relatedMove) => new
        {
            stockAndRelatedMoves.Stock.Product,
            stockAndRelatedMoves.Stock.Batch,
            Quantity = stockAndRelatedMoves.Stock.Quantity - (relatedMove?.Quantity ?? 0)
        })
    .ToList();
```

As you can see instead of `GroupBy` you need to use `GroupJoin` and instead of simple `Select` you need `SelectMany` to retrieve items from the joined records.

Some explanation:

- `stock => new { stock.Product, stock.Batch }`: Anonymous type is used here because multiple fields are used in the join
- `stockAndRelatedMoves => stockAndRelatedMoves.Moves.DefaultIfEmpty()`: it is needed because of left outer join
- `(relatedMove?.Quantity ?? 0)`: `relatedMove` can be `null` that's why we substitute it with 0

In the above code I've used the following collections:

```cs
var repository = new List<Stock>
{
    new Stock { Id = 1, Product = "AAA", Batch = "ADADAD", Quantity = 2 },
    new Stock { Id = 2, Product = "BBB", Batch = "ADADAD", Quantity = 2 },
    new Stock { Id = 3, Product = "BBB", Batch = "AAAAAA", Quantity = 2 },
};

var purchases = new List<Move>
{
    new Move { Id = 1, Product = "BBB", Batch = "ADADAD", Quantity = 1 }
};
```